# Why do some windows lack minimize buttions in LXQT?

Tags: window-decorations, lxqt, xfwm4

I recently switched to LXQT from KDE and I have realized that some windows don't have minimize buttons. They all have rollup, unroll buttons which shrink the form to the size of the titlebar only and restore it when unrolled.

**Without minimize buttons**

[image: selection_023]
[image: selection_026]

**With minimize buttons.**

[image: selection_024]
[image: selection_025]

Is there something about the forms themselves that result in LXQT not showing the minimize button or are some configuration settings required in LXQT itself for minimize buttons to be displayed on all the applicable forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After asking on the lxqt development site, https://github.com/lxde/lxqt/issues/1179#issuecomment-255884285, it turns out that I was using the `Xfwm4` window manager, and in its default configuration, it hides the minimize button on certain types of windows. In my case, the windows without minimize buttons are regular application windows and do not fall into that category, which are usually configuration dialogs and other modal dialogs.

My fix for the meantime is to switch to `Kwin` for my window manager until I learn how to configure `Xfwm4` properly.